# A system can be in motion in thermodynamic equilibrium?

Tags: thermodynamics, reference-frames, equilibrium

I mean thermodynamic equilibrium implies mechanical equilibrium, but mechanical equilibrium doesn't mean to that the system to be in static equilibrium. For some reason, all the systems I have seen in thermodynamic equilibrium are at rest. Am I wrong with this thought?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are thermodynamic quantities based on frame of reference](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/735610/) (Specifically, the quote in the first answer.)

Comment: @Chemomechanics, yes that really helped me a lot.

Comment: There are no completely closed systems. Matter exists through exchanges of energy. Isolated matter means it never exchanges energy with its surroundings. That's hard to imagine with photons everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Thermodynamic equilibrium requires no net flow of energy, no net bulk flow mass and no net molecular flow between any two points within a system. Uniform motion with respect to an inertial system of reference does not change these facts. Non-uniform motion, centrifuging for example, is a different story.